# Encoding from Arabic to Western European

Tags: c#, encoding

Please Tell Me How can I Encoding from Arabic to Western European and vice versa in C#?

for example in this [Site](http://www.string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx)   I select :

Encode with: (windows-1256)
Decode with: (windows-1252)

input is "سلام" and output is "ÓáÇã"

how can do that and vice versa with C#?

Comment: That is not possible to do in a reliable way.  Code page 1252 contains a few byte values that are not assigned.  Code 0x81 for example.  But are actually used in 1256, 0x81 is پ.  A conversion will just lose characters.  Try "چپڈ" for example, it produces *nothing*.  Never do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Assuming that the value existing in string. 
string _Value=string.Empty;
byte[] enBuff= Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256").GetBytes(_Value);
_Value= Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetString(enBuff);
```

You can alter according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi,
Please Tell Me why when I try To save on a xml file the character saved like this

   <item>&#xD3;&#xE1;&#xC7;&#xE3; &#xDA;&#xE1;&#xED; &#xCC;&#xC7;&#xE4; &#xCE;&#xE6;&#xC8;&#xED;</item>

Comment: For Xml  <?xml version="1.0" **encoding=""**?> 'encoding also you have to mention I hope.